# Simple Javascript onclick issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add onclick method to links.

I want to make a++ when user clicks the linkA and a-- when user clicks the linkB no matter what `a` value is.

My codes:

JS

```
var a=0;

function swapPost(a){

 //I want to make a++ when user click linkA;
 //a-- when user click linkB
 //not sure how to do this

   if(a>10){
    a=0;
   }
    if(a<0){
    a=0;
   }

}

swapPost(a);
```

Html

```
<a href="#" onclick="swapPost(a)">LinkA</a>
<a href="#" onclick="swapPost(a)">LinkB</a>
```

I was wondering if someone can help me out on this one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should always... **ALWAYS** use quotes on your attributes. Case-in-point here.

Comment: Right, cuz it uses `eval()` if I'm not wrong...In any case, the best you an do is separate your js from html, and forget about ugly inline scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than pass `a` in as a parameter, pass in the link which was clicked, via its id (which you have not yet defined).  Pass `this` into the function.

```
<a id='linka' href="#" onclick='swapPost(this)'>LinkA</a>
<a id='linkb' href="#" onclick='swapPost(this)'>LinkB</a>

var a=0;    
function swapPost(nodeClicked){
   // Check the id of the node passed to the function.
   if (nodeClicked.id == 'linka') {
     a++;
   }
   else if (nodeClicked.id == 'linkb') {
     a--;
   }
   else return;

   // Set to zero if outside your bounds
   if(a>10){
    a=0;
   }
    if(a<0){
    a=0;
   }
}
```

[Here it is in action](http://jsfiddle.net/LTR92/), logging to the console...

Generally it is better practice to bind functions to events rather than to code them inline into attributes.  Since `this` inside an `onclick` refers to the node which was clicked on, you don't actually need to pass it in as a parameter. You can then bind the onclick events without doing so inline, and call `this` inside.

```
<a id='linka' href="#">LinkA</a>
<a id='linkb' href="#">LinkB</a>

var a=0;    
var swapPost = function(){
   // Check the id of the node passed to the function.
   if (this.id == 'linka') {
     a++;
   }
   else if (this.id == 'linkb') {
     a--;
   }
   else return;

   // Set to zero if outside your bounds
   if(a>10){
    a=0;
   }
    if(a<0){
    a=0;
   }
}
// Bind the function to the links
document.getElementById('linka').onclick = swapPost;
document.getElementById('linkb').onclick = swapPost;
```

[Here's the updated version in action](http://jsfiddle.net/LTR92/1/)

Comment: Inline JavaScript is not recommended.

Comment: @Derek no, but that doesn't solve the OP's problem either. I'll get to event binding in a moment.

Comment: @Rouge - A better way to do is by using `addEventListener`. It can let you add more than one event to an element.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" id="a">LinkA</a>
<a href="#" id="b">LinkB</a>​
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    var a=0;
    var els=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(i=0;i<els.length;i++)
    {
        (function(i){
            els[i].onclick=function(){
                if(this.id=='a') a++;
                else a--;
                a = a < 0 ? 0 : (a > 10 ? 0 : a);
                return false;
            }
        })(i);
    }
}
</script>
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/zHwvp/5/)

Comment: hm..you answer doesn't solve my problem. I need to trigger a++ or a-- no matter what the a value is.

Comment: Your question was not obvious before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
  Javascript:

```
var a=0;
function swapPost(val){
  a=a+val;
 }
```

HTML:

```
  <a href="#" onclick='javascript:return swapPost(1);'>LinkA</a>
  <a href="#" onclick='javascript:return swapPost(-1);'>LinkB</a>
```